# Google is in German, why?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, localization

Recently I did a trip to Europe and since then, when I open Google, it's not in English anymore, is in another language (looks like Swedish or German).

'Search button' is 'Google-Suche'.

Also every site I open seems to think I speak this language too.

I already checked my google account and it's set to English, but even this way I'm having this problem.

The problem only happens in Chrome ; when i google in Safari, it shows the right language.

How to solve it?

Comment: Have you been using any VPN extensions in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has set a cookie when you used it there. The easiest way is to not use simply google.com, but *https://www.google.com/ncr* - you will always get the standard US version.

Using it once should also clean/overwite the cookie. However, my recommendation is to save the version with ncr as bookmark, or as startup page. That way, you'll never have the issue again when you travel.